# ERROR MESSAGE: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

While running script with one tax_id the output is given without any problem. But when I am adding multiple tax_ids this 'requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))' error message is appeared. ( I am running the code with over 400 tax_id and this type error appeared after a couple of outputs )

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

url = 'https://www.e-taxes.gov.az/controller'

tax_ids = [
        '1306142621',
        '1403676911',
        '1405108291',
        '5700296161',
         ]

request_payloads = {
                    "METHOD": "wsEbynGetDebetSum",
                    "voen": tax_ids,
                    }

with requests.Session() as s:
    for tax_id in tax_ids:
        request_payloads['voen'] = tax_id
        r = s.post(url, params=request_payloads)
        url_t = r.url
        response = requests.get(url_t)
        s1 = bs(response.content, 'lxml')
        output = s1.text.strip()
        debt = re.search('"debet":"(.+?)"}}', output)
        try:
            if debt:
                m = debt.group(1)
                print([tax_id] + [m])
        except ConnectionError as error:
            print(error)
            pass
```

ERROR CODE:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = {
    "METHOD": "wsEbynGetDebetSum"
}

tax_ids = ['1306142621', '1403676911', '1405108291', '5700296161']


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for tax in tax_ids:
            data['voen'] = tax
            r = req.get(url, params=data).json()
            print(r['RESULT']['debet'])


main("https://www.e-taxes.gov.az/controller")
```

Comment: I added these two lines `debt = r['RESULT']['debet']  print([tax] + [debt])` but it returns this error `in main
    debt = r['RESULT']['debet']
KeyError: 'RESULT'`

Comment: I found the reason, if the tax_id is wrong (not recognized by the system) it returns an error page. ( json : {have:0} so there is no "REASON" there )